# Linked pages not working with wordpress

Tags: admin-menu

I used this code to create a **menu page** which loads **mypluginpage.php**
and it works fine with my plugins.

I can access it from something like **http://mysite/wp-admin/admin.php?page=myplugin**

```
<?php

// Add menu
function myplugin_menu() {

    add_menu_page("myplugin", "my plugin","manage_options", "myplugin", "mypluginpage",plugins_url('/myplugin/img/icon.png'));
}

add_action("admin_menu", "myplugin_menu");

function mypluginpage(){
    include "mypluginpage.php";
}
```

**Here is my issue:** Inside **mypluginpage.php** below, I have a link that should take me to **welcome.php**  within admin page

```
<?php 
wp_head();
?>

<a href="<?php echo admin_url('welcome.php'); ?>">Take me to welcome page within admin</a>

<?php
wp_footer();
```

I thought am supposed to have something like this link below which will still keep me within admin page

**http://mysite/wp-admin/admin.php?page=welcome**

but I got

**http://mysite/wp-admin/welcome.php**

which leads me to page not found

I need to have welcome.php page to called within admin. any help will be appreciated..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was resolved by creating a sub menu page using
`add_submenu_page()` function. Thanks.